# How can I use nominal typing with mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

This isn't my exact use case, but it's similar.  Suppose I want to define two typing annotations:

```
Matrix = np.ndarray
Vector = np.ndarray
```

Now, I want a potential type-checker to complain when I pass a `Matrix` to a function that accepts a `Vector`:

```
def f(x: Vector):
    ...

m: Matrix = ...
f(m)  # Bad!
```

How do I mark these types as incompatible?

Comment: What type checker are you using? It seems like the one you're using uses structural typing, where you want nominal typing.

Comment: @jhpratt: I'm not using any type checker right now.  I will investigate the options soon.  I have been using type annotations religiously and I have about 350 annotations so far.  I would like to do this right the first time.  I don't know what structural and nominal typing means.

Comment: Perhaps try a type checker and see if it even works, then? I'm not seeing the issue right now if you haven't even done that. Structural cares about the shape of the data, nominal cares about the name of the type (essentially).

Comment: @jhpratt mypy does not complain, but I found an answer to my question.  Thank you for taking a look anyway.

Comment: Looks good! I was just taking a look at mypy's documentation and it did mention it supports nominal (which is what you wanted). Nice find.

Comment: How do you distinguish between vector and matrix?  Neither is a builtin category in numpy.  And as you observe, there's no typing framework in numpy.

Comment: @hpaulj In my code, I have two kinds of matrices (distinguished by what they represent), and I want them to remain separate, and I want the typing system to verify this.  I could have said `PolarVector` and `CartesianVector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that I can use `typing.NewType` to create distinct types:

```
from typing import NewType


A = NewType('A', int)
B = NewType('B', int)

def f(a: A):
    pass

b: B
f(b)
```

gives

```
a.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "B"; expected "A"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with `np.ndarray` until either `numpy` implements type hinting or `NewType` supports a base type of `Any`.

Comment: What? Why wouldn't it work with `numpy.ndarray`? Can you show an example of NewType failing with `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: @user2357112 Replace `int` with `np.ndarray` and run it through mypy.

Comment: Bleh, right, mypy is overreliant on stub files. It has no idea what `numpy.ndarray` even is.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, this would also fix it: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6701#issuecomment-485037387  Hopefully, this is implemented soon.